# Android: How to use strike tags of html in edittext

Tags: android, html, tags

I want to use edittext with strike tags. Of course I have already used italic, bold tags.

According to what I have found, android does not support strike tag basically.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34931560/7068422

I saw this post, but I can't follow it because of an error.

```
import android.text.Html;

public class StrikeTagHandler {
    public class HtmlTagHandler : Object, Html.ITagHandler {

    }
}
```

The error is ITagHandler does not exist.

How should I use strike tag?

T T

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
yourEditText.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

I search your question and found solutions:
Based on [Combining Spannable with String.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936901/combining-spannable-with-string-format/20937501)

YOur code should be:

```
String html = "<b>bold test</b> <u>underline test</u> <i>italic test</i> <strike>strike test 1</strike> <del>strike test 2</del> <s>strike test 3</s>";
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(html, null, new MyHtmlTagHandler());
        tv.setText(spanned);


        EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
        edt.setText(spanned);
```

and `MyHtmlTagHandler`

```
public class MyHtmlTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler {

        public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
                              XMLReader xmlReader) {
            if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("strike") || tag.equals("s")) {
                processStrike(opening, output);
            }
        }

        private void processStrike(boolean opening, Editable output) {
            int len = output.length();
            if (opening) {
                output.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), len, len, Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
            } else {
                Object obj = getLast(output, StrikethroughSpan.class);
                int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

                output.removeSpan(obj);

                if (where != len) {
                    output.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), where, len, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        }

        private Object getLast(Editable text, Class kind) {
            Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);

            if (objs.length == 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                for (int i = objs.length; i > 0; i--) {
                    if (text.getSpanFlags(objs[i - 1]) == Spannable.SPAN_MARK_MARK) {
                        return objs[i - 1];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to apply strike only to some parts of text. This method affects all text in edittext.